# Persistent user session using AWS Cognito in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, electron, amazon-cognito

### Making a AWS Cognito user session persistent in Electron

AWS Cognito stores the current user session in the `localStorage`. While the user session is present in `localStorage` after the user has logged in, `localStorage` isn't persistant in Electron - so when the application restarts, the user session is gone and the user has to log in again. Normally the user session would be recieved from `localStorage`, since it is persistent in browsers.

I know that one can use [electron-json-storage](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-json-storage) to store data persistantly in Electron and generally in node applications, but since AWS cognito uses `localStorage`, I am only able to use an approach that would change `localStorage` into being persistant, i.e redirected to a file storage.

I have tried [node-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage) which works, but cognito still uses the localStorage from the browser, even when `global.localStorage` is set.

I know that the userPool can be passed a `{Storage: ...}` object to use that as storage, but it still used the original `localStorage`, when I passed the node-localstorage to it.

TLDR;

- **How can I make the AWS Cognito user session persistent in electron?**
- **If possible, can I replace localStorage with node-localstorage globally, so that AWS Cognito will use it?**

Comment: I might be wrong in my assumptions, feel free to correct any of them

Answer (score 4):

Cognito will be giving you three tokens `idToken`, `accessToken` and `refreshToken`
A simple idea will be to save the `refreshToken` in your `localstorage` that you think is persistence. and on electron app start use that `refreshToken` to authenticate user user on Cognito.